# RestTemplate post for entity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

My post method gets called but my Profile is empty. What is wrong with this approach? Must I use @Requestbody to use the RestTemplate?

```
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.setEmail(email);        
String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/user/", profile, String.class);


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Object postUser(@Valid Profile profile, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //Profile is null
        return profile;
    }
```

Comment: Is your controller annotated to include the `user` portion of the path in `@RequestMapping`?  Because your metohd annotated points to `/`, which isn't going to respond to `/user/` without the additional controller annotation.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Yes. I am entering the controller method. The problem is that the Profile is null in the actual method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to build the profile object this way

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("email", email);

Object response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/user/", parts, String.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

`MultiValueMap` was good starting point for me but in my case it still posted empty object to `@RestController` my solution for entity creation and posting ended up looking like so:

```java
HashedMap requestBody = new HashedMap();
requestBody.put("eventType", "testDeliveryEvent");
requestBody.put("sendType", "SINGLE");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

// Jackson ObjectMapper to convert requestBody to JSON
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);

restTemplate.postForEntity("/generate", entity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

My current approach:

```java
final Person person = Person.builder().name("antonio").build();

final ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
         new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/person/aggregate").toString(),
         person, Person.class);
```