# Make Rest Client using Spring Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, rest-client

Here is my spring controller code..

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/save_item",
method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")

public @ResponseBody ModelMap saveItem(ModelMap model,
@RequestParam("id") String itemId,
@RequestParam("name") String itemName) {

model.addAttribute("itemId",itemId);
return model;
}
```

How can i make a rest client using spring rest tempalte?.

I need to send two parameters from my rest client(id,name).
Anyone Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestTemplate post for entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728006/resttemplate-post-for-entity)

Comment: in that example they only send a request using restTemplate.postForObject.i also need to specify accept header in my request.how can i possible that

Comment: refer to this question for post with accept headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/set-accept-header-for-spring-rest-template.

Comment: it does not wok for me..can u give an example for it?

Comment: Anyone please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a RestTemplate object and execute as this

```
ResponseEntity<List<City>> result = restTemplate.exchange(
                new StringBuilder(URL).append(city).toString(),
                HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType);
```

In this project you can find a maven project with spring-boot and sptring-web that uses this restTemplate snippet and jackson for the json response

https://github.com/voliveirajr/dev-test